# Execute remote query on linked server in Postgre

Tags: postgresql, t-sql

In T-SQL there is EXECUTE AT function to execute against linked server. Is there a way to make the same call to linked server in Postgre?
If i'm correct then it's just something like that:

EXEC [LINKEDSERVERNAME].[DB]...

Tried to google it but couldn't find a suitable answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, you can execute remote queries against other databases or servers using the `dblink` extension or by setting up a foreign data wrapper (FDW). Here's how you can achieve this:

**Using the `dblink` Extension**:

1. Ensure the `dblink` extension is installed. You can install it using the following command:

   ```sql
   CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
   ```
2. To execute a query on a remote server, you can use the `dblink` functions. Here's a basic example:

   ```sql
   SELECT *
   FROM dblink('dbname=myremotedb host=myremotehost user=myuser password=mypassword', 'SELECT * FROM remote_table') AS t(id int, name text);
   ```

   Replace `myremotedb`, `myremotehost`, `myuser`, `mypassword`, and `remote_table` with your specific remote database information and query.

**Using Foreign Data Wrappers (FDW)**:

1. PostgreSQL supports Foreign Data Wrappers (FDW), which allows you to connect to and query remote databases as if they were local.
2. First, create a foreign server that represents your remote server:

   ```sql
   CREATE SERVER myserver
   FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
   OPTIONS (host 'myremotehost', dbname 'myremotedb');
   ```
3. Next, create a user mapping for the user on the remote server:

   ```sql
   CREATE USER MAPPING FOR local_user
   SERVER myserver
   OPTIONS (user 'remote_user', password 'remote_password');
   ```
4. Create a foreign table that represents the remote table:

   ```sql
   CREATE FOREIGN TABLE my_remote_table (
       id int,
       name text
   )
   SERVER myserver
   OPTIONS (table_name 'remote_table');
   ```
5. You can now query the remote table as if it were a local table:

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM my_remote_table;
   ```

Replace `myserver`, `local_user`, `remote_user`, `remote_password`, `myremotehost`, `myremotedb`, and `remote_table` with your specific details.

These methods allow you to execute remote queries in PostgreSQL, similar to the T-SQL `EXECUTE AT` function when working with linked servers in SQL Server.